# Python 3 error: "IndexError: index 140 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 100"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from numpy import zeros,linspace

N = 100
points = N**2
x1,x2 = -2,2
y1,y2 = -2,2

m_array = zeros([N,N],float)

i,j = -1,0

for x in linspace(x1,x2,N):
    i += 1
    for y in linspace(y1,y2,N):
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            continue
        else:
            c = complex(x,y)           
            z = 0
            if abs(c)<2:
                for k in range(0,101):
                    zprime = abs(z) + c
                    z = zprime
                if abs(z) < 2:
                    m_array[i,j] = 1
                    j += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    j += 1
                    continue
            else:
                j += 1
                continue
```

N.B. the range of 'k' is arbitrary, it just needs to be relatively large.

I have read through several of the previous questions on the website but I can't seem to find the problem in my own code. This is my attempt at plotting the Mandelbrot set using a density plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continue here applies to the `for y in linspace(y1,y2,N):` loop - not the `for x in linspace(x1,x2,N):` loop.

```
if abs(z) < 2:
    m_array[i,j] = 1
    j += 1
    continue
```

Therefore, `j` can be more than 99.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Following your help, after a bit of tinkering, I got it working.

Comment: @DominicWilliamson No problem. Do you mind also upvoting me pease?

Comment: Hi, I would do but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet :(